# .Net Core 3.1 with SoapCore - how to run it in Docker?

Tags: .net, docker, soap, docker-compose, dockerfile

Normally, the endpoint would work with: http://localhost:5000/Service.asmx. 
How can I access this from a client that runs in a separate container? I tried to get the ip of the net core container and I replaced the localhost.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dotnet_soap_example.dll"]
```

I ran it with:

```
docker build -t dotnet_soap_example .
docker run -p 5000:5000 dotnet_soap_example
```

And the result is:

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
      Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {89888afb-2afd-4798-8474-9b71d743a397} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:80
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /app
```

Also, when I created the project I did that with:

```
dotnet new web
```

and I installed SoapCore NuGet package:

```
dotnet add package SoapCore
```

Is this NuGet installation necessary to be added in the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Replaced `5000:5000` with `5000:80`